# How air gets filled in bicycle tire without removing its valve tube?

Tags: everyday-life, air

If I remove valve tube from tire, air inside the tire comes out.

but we fill the tire with air pump without removing its valve tube.

by doing this air gets filled it.

How something going in with closed state ?

Comment: This is not exactly  a question on physics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets filled in only one direction because the valve is there, a valve is like a door that can only move in one direction ( because it is blocked to move in the other direction by a piece of metal or by some other thing) so when you fill air inside your tyre valve moves down due to the pressure of your bike pump and when you are done filing the air, it prevents the inside air from coming out because that metal piece prevents it from moving back, its stuck at that location.